# can't connect to solr server when rebuilding index for django haystack

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

I am getting the following error:

> Failed to add documents to Solr: Failed to connect to server at
>   'http://example.com/:8983/solr/update/?commit=true', are you sure
>   that URL is correct? Checking it in a browser might help:
>   HTTPConnectionPool(host='example.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded
>   with url: /:8983/solr/update/?commit=true (Caused by : [Errno 111] Connection refused)

I can hit the commit=true address which returns this xml:
[image]

I can hit the solr admin with no problem:
[image]

I have opened all ports in my security group especially 8983 and 80.

Here is my settings entry:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://example.com/:8983/solr',
        'TIMEOUT': 60 * 5,
    },
}
```

Why can't I connect to rebuild the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was here:

```
'URL': 'http://example.com/:8983/solr',
```

It should be this:

```
'URL': 'http://example.com:8983/solr',
```